# Removing cached pages in asp.net on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Asp.net is able to cache pages using the [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directive.  Is it is possible to remove a page from the cache if a postback occurs?  I have tried using RemoveOutputCacheItem(Absolute Page path) in Page_load with the IsPostback conditional and although the code runs the page stubbornly stays in the cache.

Any ideas on how to clear a page from cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Expires = -1500;
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        }
```

Comment: That's the HTTP client cache control, not the ASP.NET server-side output cache.